# how to make cookies and remember answer for iphone/android devices?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this code in my index.html

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ) {
            if (document.cookie.indexOf('iphone_redirect=false') == -1) {
                if (confirm('for your device exist iphone app')) {
                    window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/....';
                }
            }
        }


        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var isAndroid = ua.indexOf('android') > -1;
        if(isAndroid) {
            if (confirm('for your device exist iphone app')) { 
                window.location = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=...';
            }
        }
```

But i don't know how to make cookie to remember my answer. If user click "cancel" or "OK" to remember "cancel" or "OK" until user clean cache.

Do you have idea how to make cookie to remember answer?

Comment: What if a user clicked cancel by mistake?

Comment: if user later erase cache, then it will appear again. But i don't know how to make cookie to remember answer? This is my main problem.

Comment: If you don't want to pass this information to the server and just have the client browser decide, use _localStorage_ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using *localStorage* (phrase it so the default is *falsey*)

```
// save a flag
window.localStorage.setItem('iphone_no_redirect', 'true'); // any truthy string

// check a flag
if (window.localStorage.getItem('iphone_no_redirect')) {
     // this has a truthy value
} else {
     // this has a falsey value ("" or null)
}

// remove a flag
window.localStorage.removeItem('iphone_no_redirect');

// make flag falsy without removing it, set to ""
window.localStorage.setItem('iphone_no_redirect', '');
```

You can check against `null` if you want to know if a flag is set and falsey

```
// flag set but falsey
var x = window.localStorage.getItem('iphone_no_redirect');
if (!x && x !== null) { // x is falsey, x is not null
    // ...
}
```

---

Combining this with a `confirm`,

```
function ask(question, key, overwrite) {
    var response;
    if (!overwrite) { // if not overwriting, check first
        response = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (response !== null) { // has been asked before
            if (['', 'false', 'no', '0', 'null', 'undefined'].indexOf(response) !== -1)
                return false; // negative answers
            return true; // anything else is a positive answer
        }
    }
    if (overwrite === 2) { // easy cleanup
        window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
        return; // die
    }
    // not been asked before or we are overwriting previous answer
    response = confirm(question);
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, response.toString()); // "true" or "false"
    return response;
}
```

---

In action

```
console.log(ask('Are you human?', 'is_human')); // this causes confirm dialog
console.log(ask('Are you human?', 'is_human')); // this doesn't need to ask

// changing a previous answer
console.log(ask('Are you human?', 'is_human', 1)); // this causes confirm dialog again

// cleanup
ask(null, 'is_human', 2); // (don't need question for this)
```

Comment: Thank you for help. How this to implement with my example above? Could you help?

Comment: Thank you for answer. But how to implement this code with mine in first post?